# Removing platform.sh integration from DDEV

Tags: integration

I set up platform.sh integration with DDEV according to the docs: https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/providers/platform/

However, now I want to remove that integration, but the docs don't say how to do so. Can anyone assist?

Answer (score 0):

In the end I removed `.ddev/.ddev.platformsh.yml` and reloaded DDEV. It worked, but there are still traces left in my file system. I wish there was an uninstaller.